# Unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll in adt.Fill(ds)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm a newbie in vb.net. I would like to ask for your help why I'm having this error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll on adt.Fill(ds)"

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form2

    'global declarations

    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim adt As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:/Users/ACER 170/Desktop/Document Tracking DOLE/MS Access Database/DocumentTrackingdata.accdb;"

        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        adt = New OleDbDataAdapter("INSERT INTO Table1 (TrackingNumber) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "')", con)

        adt.Fill(ds)
        MsgBox("YES!")

        Timer1.Stop()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Read the Docs about [OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery). See to what SQL statements it appllies.

Comment: You have not assigned anything to ds

Comment: You Fill a DataSet with a Select statement. You have an Insert statement so no data is returned. (An Insert will return rows affected. Also, it looks like you want a StopWatch not a Timer unless you are using the Timer.Tick event somewhere.